# Extending Array from custom Sequence in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm essentially trying to:

1. Make custom protocols descended from Sequence and Generator as `SpecialSequence` and `SpecialGenerator`
2. Implement `SpecialGenerator` as `SpecialGen`
3. Extend Array to implement `SpecialSequence`

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
protocol SpecialGenerator: Generator {
    typealias T;
    func next() -> T?;
    //...
}

class SpecialGen<T>: SpecialGenerator {
    var Objects: Array<T>;
    var CurrIndex = 0;

    init(objs: Array<T>) {
        self.Objects = objs;
    }

    func next() -> T? {
        return Objects[CurrIndex];
    }
    //...
}

protocol SpecialSequence: Sequence {
    typealias T;
    func generate() -> SpecialGenerator;
    //...
}

extension Array: SpecialSequence {
    func generate() -> SpecialGenerator {
        return SpecialGen(objs: self);
    }
}
```

But I get the error `Array<T> does not conform to protocol "SpecialSequence"`

I've also tried using various combinations of `SpecialGenerator` and `SpecialGen<T>` as return types to no avail.

Is this possible in Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to supply a value for the type alias you defined

```
protocol SpecialSequence: Sequence {
    typealias Foo;
    func generate() -> SpecialGenerator;
    //...
}
extension Array: SpecialSequence {
    typealias Foo = T
    func generate() -> SpecialGenerator {
        return SpecialGen(objs: self);
    }
}
```

This compiles for me

Comment: I get "use of undeclared type U" when I do that :\

Comment: I modified the previous answer now that I'm in front of a compiler :)